# How to set up an OSM routing server

Tags: openstreetmap, routing

I would like to set up an OSM routing server on my LAMP stack. I am interested in doing a lot of of routing queries.  I have a search function that is closely related to getting the driving distance between lat/long locations and will thus be handling a lot of routing queries, even in a development environment.  I know how to use the Mapquest API but would like to set up an OSM routing server before I sign up for a business licence with a proprietary mapping service.  Where would I start this project? I have looked at [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) and [osm4routing](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing) but am still a bit bewildered and can't find anything very well documented out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Building OSRM](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Building%20OSRM), [Running OSRM](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Running-OSRM). Two links away from the OSRM homepage.

Comment: so OSRM is the way to go.  Are there other options available.

Comment: Yes, but not better ones.